# "error libnfc.driver.acr122_usb Unable to write to USB (Connection timed out)"

Tags: ubuntu, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard, acr122

I installed required package to use my ACR122U contactless smart card reader in Ubuntu-14-LTS. Fortunately it's work fine:

```
ebrahim@ubuntu:~$ pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.22 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.10
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: ACS ACR122U 00 00

Mon Jun 29 05:16:00 2015
Reader 0: ACS ACR122U 00 00
  Card state: Card removed,
```

But when I want to use my reader with [mfoc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfoc) tool, I receive the following error and my reader disable (Its LED freeze and absence or presence of the card doesn't create any beep, Normally the LED change to green and red when I move a card inside or outside of its range + generating a beep voice)

```
^C
ebrahim@ubuntu:~$ mfoc -O test.mfd
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to write to USB (Connection timed out)
No NFC device found.
ebrahim@ubuntu:~$
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to boot Kali from a USB to get this to work.  That does not solve the problem of running it in a VM, but it does allow you to do what you needed to do (two and a half years ago).

https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/369